# Results of an UNION in two columns

Tags: sql, presto

I am querying names from two tables:

```
with data_1 as (
select names from tbl1),

data_2 as (
select names from tbl2)

select * from data_1
union
select * from data_2
```

And I get the result I want in a single column.

Now I want to know if it is possbile to get the results in two different columns like:  `"names_from_data1", "names_from_data2"`

Or another way to identify where each name comes from: `data_1` or `data_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add hardcoded column to indicate the source:

```sql
with data_1 as (
select names, 'tbl1' as source from tbl1),

data_2 as (
select names, 'tbl2' as source from tbl2)

select * from data_1
union
select * from data_2
```